# React Native upgrade to 0.40.0 linking issues

Tags: react-native

I went thru https://github.com/ncuillery/rn-diff/compare/rn-0.39.2...rn-0.40.0 and moved over what seemed to be meaningful, but not what I assume to be compile results.

My remaining issues may be specific to my project, but also likely affect others. Does anyone know how to solve these?

[image: screen shot 2017-01-08 at 4 03 26 am]
[image: screen shot 2017-01-08 at 4 03 52 am]
[image: screen shot 2017-01-08 at 4 04 13 am]

---

See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11721#issuecomment-271146805

Comment: This answer is being discussed at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11721

Comment: Might not help but we wrote a blog post about our experiences: https://medium.com/tido-music/upgrading-react-native-from-0-39-0-to-0-42-3-in-a-hybrid-app-e69dff1f4688